# how to change showModalBottomSheet default transition effect

Tags: flutter

I want to apply some custom transition to showModalBottomSheet.

something like SlideTransition or FadeTransition.

```dart
@override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: FractionalTranslation(
        translation: _offsetTween.evaluate(_animation!),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
```

How to achieve this kind of effect?

Comment: Do you want to achieve bottom sheet height transition or when showing the animation

Comment: @HemanthS I want to apply fadeTransition effect to bottom sheet and replace the default one.also i want to control the animation duration and ease function.